# Racket GUI Toolkit: How to embed a link

Tags: user-interface, racket

Say we have a frame

```
(define my-frame (new frame% [parent #f] [label "test"]))
```

and a message, that should link to google.

```
(new message%
    [parent my-frame]
    [label "https://www.google.com"])

(send my-frame show #t)
```

The above does not work. How does one embed a link in the Racket GUI toolkit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the button, but I guess that isn't link-like so you don't want it, the following code shows how to use editor **clickback** to create a link-like text.

```lisp
(require net/sendurl)

(define f (new frame% [parent #f]
               [label "test"]
               [width 300]
               [height 300]))

(define editor (new text%))
(new editor-canvas% [parent f]
     [editor editor])

(define t "https://www.google.com")
(send editor insert t)
(send editor set-clickback 0 (string-length t)
      (λ (text start end)
        (send-url t)))

(send* f
  [show #t]
  [center])
```

Comment: You might also want to call the editor's `lock` and `hide-caret` methods.